# .NET Core - Migration Fluent API HasColumnType

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using .NET CORE 2.2 and EF CORE for SQLSERVER and PostgreSQL.

In postgresql doesn't exists varchar(max) or varchar(-1) like on SQLSERVER,in  postgresql the data type is TEXT.

On this column, I need it to be varchar(max) for the SQL server and text for Postgres., How can it be done?

That migration needs to be understood by each provider.

I appreciate your help.

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Foo).HasColumnType("varchar(-1)");
```

sorry, my English is not so good.

Comment: If you don't specify the column type, won't it use varchar(max) / text for string properties?

Comment: Yes, I tried and work. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default ColumnType of string will automatically map to the Max length field. so be leaving off the column type you should get what you want.

`builder.Property(x => x.Foo)`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the approach you are using if its Database first or Code first approach

- For Database First: You can simply run the below script in the package manager console and making sure to have set the default project where you want the import to be

---

For MSSQL

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxxxxx;Database=TestDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -F -OutputDir Models
```

The above will generate virtually all the properties of the tables

---

For Postgres

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "{YourConnectionString}" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -F -OutputDir Models
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, because I'm using Fluent API with Migration. The database is created by class maps

Comment: Sorry, I want to understand. Are you using Two different Database in a project?

Comment: Yes. My client can be choose the database between SQLSERVER and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, using the default should give you what you want, i.e. max length for your text column.

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Foo)
```

However, if you want to be explicit and not use the default values, you may use something like this:

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Foo).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

If you only want to change the maximum length, this api is also available:

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Foo).HasMaxLength(50);
```